# How to add attribute to the root of JSON object consists of array of objects?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

How to add attribute to the root of JSON object consists of array of objects?

If my JSON object something like that:

```
 [
   {
      "Id":"f2ac41c5-b214-48f6-ad40-9fc35c1aaad9",
      "Name":"W",
      "NumberOfWorkHours":8,
      "NumberOfShortDays":1,
      "WorkTimeRegulationId":"f5833075-2847-4cc3-834d-6138dd0dcd99"
   },
   {
      "Id":"5c267601-fcf2-4735-9e49-b4def3981648",
      "Name":"S",
      "NumberOfWorkHours":6,
      "NumberOfShortDays":0,
      "WorkTimeRegulationId":"8d14580e-278f-41d1-9239-8874be792580"
   }
]
```

I do the following:

```
worktimeJSON.Id = $('.Js-WorkTime-id').val();
worktimeJSON.Name = $('.Js-WorkTime-name').val();
worktimeJSON.NumberOfAvailableRotations = $('.Js-WorkTime-rotations').val();
```

And make sure that the jQuery fetching data from the inputs but this doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I structure my object like this:

---

```
 let WorkTimeRegulationViewModelJSON = {
                Id: $('.Js-WorkTimeRegulation-id').val(),
                Name: $('.Js-WorkTimeRegulation-name').val(),
                NumberOfAvailableRotations: $('.Js-WorkTimeRegulation-rotations').val(),
                AssignedWorkTimes: JSON.parse(worktimeJSON)

            };
```

Answer (score 3):

This will change property of all object in array if you want to change in particular then use index for this for exp->

```
worktimeJSON[0].Id = $('.Js-WorkTime-id').val();
worktimeJSON[0].Name = $('.Js-WorkTime-name').val();
worktimeJSON[0].NumberOfAvailableRotations = $('.Js-WorkTime-rotations').val();
```

```js
var worktimeJSON = [
   {
      "Id":"f2ac41c5-b214-48f6-ad40-9fc35c1aaad9",
      "Name":"W",
      "NumberOfWorkHours":8,
      "NumberOfShortDays":1,
      "WorkTimeRegulationId":"f5833075-2847-4cc3-834d-6138dd0dcd99"
   },
   {
      "Id":"5c267601-fcf2-4735-9e49-b4def3981648",
      "Name":"S",
      "NumberOfWorkHours":6,
      "NumberOfShortDays":0,
      "WorkTimeRegulationId":"8d14580e-278f-41d1-9239-8874be792580"
   }
];

worktimeJSON = worktimeJSON.map(function(val){
    val.Id = $('.Js-WorkTime-id').val();
    val.Name = $('.Js-WorkTime-name').val();
    val.NumberOfAvailableRotations = $('.Js-WorkTime-rotations').val();
    return val;
});
```

Comment: @AnynameDonotcare this should work. Is your JSON named worktimeJSON ?

Comment: @Cid yeah and I call the method in `$("body").on("click", "#btnSave", function () `

Comment: @AnynameDonotcare can you put some more code for getting your exact issue, It will work if  `worktimeJSON` is defined and coming as array.

Comment: `$("body").on("click", "#btnSave", function () {

        var worktimeJSON = kendo.stringify($("#grid").data("kendoGrid").dataSource.view());


        worktimeJSON = worktimeJSON.map(function (val) {
            val.Id = $('.Js-WorkTimeRegulation-id').val();
            val.Name = $('.Js-WorkTimeRegulation-name').val();
            val.NumberOfAvailableRotations = $('.Js-WorkTimeRegulation-rotations').val();
            return val;
        });`

Comment: Can you print `worktimeJSON` ? and update in your question.

Comment: @AnynameDonotcare `.stringify(..)` will convert the json into a string, not an array of objects. You can't apply `.map()` or any array methods.

Comment: @cid I Just want to get a JSON object consists of array of objects +these attributes out of the array on the root

Comment: @Cid but when i `console.log(kendo.stringify($("#grid").data("kendoGrid").dataSource.view())` I get json object !

Comment: @AnynameDonotcare No. You don't get a JSON object, you get a JSON string.

Comment: @Cid Thanks a lot for your help and Nishant Dixit I'm really grateful

Answer (score 2):

Push can do the job.

```js
let worktimeJSON = [
   {
      "Id":"f2ac41c5-b214-48f6-ad40-9fc35c1aaad9",
      "Name":"W",
      "NumberOfWorkHours":8,
      "NumberOfShortDays":1,
      "WorkTimeRegulationId":"f5833075-2847-4cc3-834d-6138dd0dcd99"
   },
   {
      "Id":"5c267601-fcf2-4735-9e49-b4def3981648",
      "Name":"S",
      "NumberOfWorkHours":6,
      "NumberOfShortDays":0,
      "WorkTimeRegulationId":"8d14580e-278f-41d1-9239-8874be792580"
   }
];

worktimeJSON.push
({
 id: "someID",
 name: "toto",
 WorkTimeRegulationId: 42
});

console.log(worktimeJSON);
```

Comment: I want some thing like the following structure please :
`My Obj = {
            Id: $('.Js-WorkTime-id').val(),
            Name:  $('.Js-WorkTime-name').val(),
            NumberOfAvailableRotations: $('.Js-WorkTime-rotations').val(),
            AssignedWorkTimes: worktimeJSON

        };`